# Food a vegan should eat after weight lifting that is intended to build mass muscle?

Tags: nutrition

What food should I eat? 
I am assuming the aim is to eat food that has protien in it.. 
And the aim is to have the protien being absorbed fast.

Should I use a food supplement? such as a powder?

Answer (score 6):

Your post exercise meal should be a mix of carbs and protein. Fast or slow absorption has not been shown to be an issue for amateur athletes--adequate protein intake is an issue.

For a vegan this could be any mix of foods which should be part of your existing diet.  Emphasis should be placed on proteins which have a higher completeness score and high [Biological Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_value).

The following link from PubMed contains an article in the Journal of Sports Science and Medicine on protein: [Hoffman JR, Falvo MJ. Protein – Which is Best? Journal of Sports Science & Medicine. 2004;3(3):118-130.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3905294/)

Per that source, Black Beans and Soy Protein (isolate or concentrate) are your two best options, along with rice protein, and any other vegetable based proteins available such as TVP.

Guidelines for amount of protein to intake are around 20g/meal.  Your total requirements are around 1g of protein for each kg of lean bodyweight per day.

Comment: Great answer, backed with supporting sources. Welcome to fitness.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I would say Pea Protein is generally better than Soy Protein from most articles I've read. Not a Vegan though so no first hand experience to support.

Answer (score 3):

Vegan protein sources:

1. **Green peas** - Black eyed peas have more protein but are harder to come by.
2. **Nuts** - Includes cashews, walnuts, almonds, peanuts...
3. **Tofu**
4. **Quinoa** - my personal favorite. Very tasty and fills multiple needs, namely protein, many minerals, vitamins, also carbohydrates and fiber! It is the ace of vegan foods.
5. **Beans**
6. **Soy**
7. **Lentils**
8. **Tempeh**
9. **Seitan**
10. **Spinach**
11. **Broccoli**
12. **ETC** There are many others, seeds etc...

A food supplement is always good, it is practical and sometimes cheaper. There are many good ones that are soy based but in my opinion the best protein supplements are those based on peas. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the book Eat and Run by Scott Jurek. He lists many recipes for vegetarians and this includes some vegan ones too. He is an ultra marathoner (living) legend and has had this philosophy of getting enough protein in mind from the beginning of his career.